# Login form sleep() with bcrypt

Tags: php, security, authentication

is there any point using sleep() to stop brute force attacks if passwords are stored by bcrypt with `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` and `['cost' => 12]`

Login form uses standard `password_verify`

```
if (!password_verify($password, $check_password)) {
```

I've noticed that increasing the cost to 16 will significantly increase the login time upon submit. Does it work the same way as sleep() and if so, can it be exploited to DOS the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cost factor is meant to stop offline brute force attacks (i.e. after someone grabs hashes from the database). Bcrypt is already too slow for practical *online* brute force attacks. Exception: If your password is one of the [10,000 most common](http://www.wired.com/2013/12/web-semantics-the-ten-thousand-worst-passwords/), it is trivial to guess. What you want, instead of increasing the cost factor, is to focus on [rate limiting your login attempts](https://timoh6.github.io/2015/05/07/Rate-limiting-web-application-login-attempts.html).

Comment: Thank you. How about DOS attacks? Can they exploit the cost time of bcrypt the same way as with the sleep()?

Comment: `sleep()` isn't a DoS vector; bcrypt can be. Choose a cost parameter that is acceptable (i.e. 125 ms -> 8 logins per core per second is your authentication bottleneck).

Comment: it's better to rate-limit the client by demanding proof of work. Make user agent calculate the prime factors of a large number. it's trivially fast to validate on the server, but slow to calculate on the client